# In the set $(\mathbb N^{+})^{\mathbb N}$ we have partially ordered set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

> In the set $(\mathbb N^{+})^{\mathbb N}$ we have partially ordered set: $$f \le g \Leftrightarrow (\forall n \in \mathbb N) f(n)|g(n).$$ (a) Whether the partially ordered set $\left\langle (\mathbb N^{+})^{\mathbb N}, \le\right\rangle $ has the smallest element? 
> (b) Let $A=\left\{ f \in (\mathbb N^{+})^{\mathbb N}: (\forall n \in \mathbb N) f(n) \ge 2\right\} $. Prove that set of all minimal elements of $A$ is infinite.
>  (c) Let $f_{1}: \mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb N^{+}$ where $f_{1}(n)=n+1$ and $f_{2}: \mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb N^{+}$ is a function which is constantly equal to $2$ for every $n \in \mathbb N$. Find supremum $\left\{ f_{1}, f_{2} \right\} $  in the partialy ordered set $\left\langle (\mathbb N^{+})^{\mathbb N}, \le\right\rangle $.

My solution:
(a) I think the answer is $0$ because if $f(n)=g(n)$ then remainder of the division $f(n)$ by $g(n)$ is $0$. However I don't know how to prove it. 
Moreover I don't have idea how to do other tasks: (b) and (c).

Can you help me and talk me what to look for to learn to do this type of task?

Comment: Is $0$ a member of the $\mathbb{N}$ of the exponent? [so that's why it has no plus sign] If not, either both need a plus or neither.

Comment: @coffeemath $\mathbb N=\left\{ 0,1,2,... \right\} $ and $\mathbb N^{+}=\left\{ 1,2,... \right\} =\mathbb N - \left\{0\right\}$

Comment: It can't be $0$ because $0$ isn't a function.

Comment: For (a) try the function that is always $1$, for (b) the idea is similar coupled with the question "How many primes are there?", for (c) I would try $n\mapsto \operatorname{mmc}(f_1(n), f_2(n))$.